# why object properties are coming as undefined when i already set them

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototype

```
function detail(){
  this.html = this.name;
}

var detail1 = new detail();
detail1.name = 'xyz';
console.log(detail1.html);
```

The above code gives `undefined` as output. But I already set the name to 'xyz'; I am new to **object oriented JavaScript**. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `name` is `undefined` when you initialize the `html` property by copying it.

A solution would be to pass it in the constructor :

```
function detail(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.html = this.name;
}

var detail1 = new detail();
console.log(detail1.html);
```

Another solution would be to make html a function :

```
function detail(){
}
detail.prototype.html = function(){
   return this.name;
}
var detail1 = new detail();
detail1.name = 'xyz';
console.log(detail1.html()); // <- notice the parenthesis here : html is a function
```

And a third one would be to change `html` when you change the `name` :

```
function detail(){
}
detail.prototype.setName = function(name){
   this.html = name;
}
var detail1 = new detail();
'xyz';
detail1.setName('xyz');
console.log(detail1.html);
```

Comment: So all the object properties should be given as parameters to function?

Comment: @user1411662 Not necessarily : there are other solutions (see edit). You'll have to choose the most practical for you.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the name as a parameter to the function.  Currently when a new instance of the detail object is created, its name property is undefined.  It is being set after the call to the constructor, which is too late.

```
function detail(name){
  this.html = "<li><a href='#'>"+name+"</a><a>"+"<li>";
}

var detail1 = new detail('xyz');
console.log(detail1.html);
```